# Проблемы с формированием списка в Python

Tags: python, list

Список должен формироваться по построчному вводу. Т.е. если ввод:

```
1
2
3
```

То список должен получиться:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Подскажите, как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# создание пустого списка

lst = []

# количество элементов в качестве входных данных

n = int(input("Введите количество элементов для списка : "))

# итерация до диапазона

for i in range(0, n):
    ele = input()

    lst.append(ele)  # добавление элемента

print(lst)
```